# icc: including omp.h requires byteswap.h

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, icc

Just tried to compile my code (which works perfectly fine with gcc) using icc-11.
If I include `omp.h` I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/bits/byteswap.h(47): error: identifier "__builtin_bswap32" is undefined
    return __builtin_bswap32 (__bsx);
           ^

/usr/include/bits/byteswap.h(111): error: identifier "__builtin_bswap64" is undefined
    return __builtin_bswap64 (__bsx);
```

The same happens if I include `stdlib.h`.

I'm really confused and I don't even know what byteswap is good for. I've issued the `iccvars_intel64.sh` script before compiling. Doesn't help much though.

Any ideas?

P.S.: Do I even need to include `omp.h` if want to parallelize some loops? Maybe I could simply omit `#include <omp.h>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately ICC 11.0 does not support `__builtin_bswap32` and `__builtin_bswap64`. You're probably getting these errors since `byteswap.h` is included internally by `omp.h` and `stdlib.h`. This issue has also been reported in this [LLVM bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4614).

Basically, your system headers are "newer" and not compatible with ICC 11.0.

Since the bswap builtins are supported in more recent ICC versions (at least since 13.0, according to [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/JuVjfT)), one option is upgrading to a more recent ICC.

Alternatively, you'll need to use standard headers that are compatible with ICC 11.0, instead of your system ones, as explained in this Intel Developer Zone [thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/277154). One way to go is installing a GCC version that "matches" ICC 11.0, and then tell ICC to use the headers bundled with that GCC. According to 
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_Compiler), ICC 11.0 was released on Nov. 2008, so the [GCC 4.2](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-4.2/) release series may be compatible (see here for other [GCC releases](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/releases.html)).